# PHP Date in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this query?

```
 $query = $db->query("select username from roomsbooked where username='$_SESSION[username]' and timeslot='$_SESSION[timeslot]' and number='$_SESSION[roomNumberToBook]' and dateofbooking='$_SESSION[dateEntered]'");
```

The dateofbooking field in the database is a "date" field.

$_SESSION[dateEntered] is defined as:

```
$_SESSION["dateEntered"] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST["Date"]);
```

When the script runs it gets to the query but nothing happens there after.

Comment: Date fields are stored with Y-m-d format in MySQL

Comment: I've made that change but it's still showing "0000-00-00" in the database field.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL Doesnt use `d/m/Y` format, you have to do

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST["Date"]);
```